# Does My Angular HTTPClient POST Request this simple URL Post Request

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want to send one simple parameter to an IP Address and port on a local network.  In Postman, this looks like sending a POST request with the URL 192.168.4.2:80/?led=1 .  This sends the parameter led=1 to the IP address and port.  I'm trying to do this simple operation with Angular's HTTP Client, but am confused on whether I should use headers or not.  I don't use Headers when I send the URL in Postman, do I need to use headers in HTTPClient?  I'd also like to just send a URL (192.168.4.2:80/?led=1) if possible, but I get an error if I don't include parameters.

Here's my code so far.

```
sendData (myNumber) {
    //var headers = new Headers();
    //let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    console.log(this.http.post('http://192.168.4.2:80/','led=1', httpOptions).subscribe(data=>console.log(data)))
  }
```

SO basic questions are 1. am I accomplishing what I want to accomplish? and 2. Is there a way to just send a URL POST request in Angular, or do I need to send a POST request with URL, Parameters, and Headers?  I assume the function does some string parsing under the hood, but I'm not sure if it's accomplishing the end goal.
Also is there a way to log what HTTPClient is actually sending to the server (i.e. the End product)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the documentation on `POST` and see what you are currently passing: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post, you are sending as body, but you seem to be looking for `HttpParams`. Please refer to the documentation as whole: https://angular.io/guide/http and look specifically at the url query strings.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Is there a way to send a URL request without a body?

Comment: I want to just send a HTTP request with a URL.  I don't want to send something with a body and headers

Comment: Send an empty body ```{}```?

Comment: well if you have a post request, but don't want to pass data as body, you can send for example `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Create HttpParams object and set parameter values.

Example:

**HttpParams params = new new HttpParams({fromObject: {"param1": 1", "param2", 2}});**

This is equivalent as **/?param1=1&param2=2**

For your code

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }),
    params: new HttpParams({
        fromObject: {"led": 1} 
    })
};

this.http.post("http://192.168.4.2:80", {}, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Reference

[Angular HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)

Comment: Thank you so much!!  This was really easy to understand

Comment: I'm trying this out now in the IDE, only note is  {"led":1} causes an error but {"led":"1"} works just fine.